# How do we install firefox-esr 52.9.0 on Debian 9?

Tags: firefox, debian, version

I'm working on a project where I need a firefox-esr version 52.9.0 or lower on a Debian 9 but when I check firefox-version with `apt-cache policy firefox-esr` I only have 60.x versions available.

I've tried so many things to downgrade my actual version or to download directly the 52.9.0 version like using dpkg -i and mozilla ftp, ppa list such as jonathonf's one without success.

I'm really looking for help to finally have this 52.9.0 firefox's version I need so if anyone have a secret solution, I'm taking it :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain...  I too want to keep my legacy XUL browser.  Here's how to do
it...

Goto:  https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/52.9.0esr/

- Download the release for your machine architecture...
- Disable your internet connection !important
- Install FF52.9.0esr
- goto [about:config]
- Start Firefox and Type  [app.update.]  into the searchbar
- Toggle the options to [false] for all boolian [app.update] entries

Now your Firefox won't (silently) auto-update to the latest esr the minute you go online.

For me,  this was necessary to regain use of the 130+ "legacy" xul addons that I've
come to depend on over the years...  addons that Mozilla, in its infinite wisdom
has removed from addons.mozilla.org thus being dorks about user preference.  Well
here's how to get around this too.

- Goto: https://legacycollector.org/firefox-addons/

Install whichever XUL extension you like.

Hope this solves your issue.
--[ Hummer ]--